# crafting direct jump in visual studio

Tags: c, assembly, visual-studio-2012, x86

I want to a direct jump in Visual Studio. Because Visual Studio uses MASM which does not support direct jumps like jmp 0x12345678 I want to craft this jump with its op code. My code looks like this

```
//0xEA = jmpf, 0x11223344 = jump target, 0x002e = code segment
unsigned char jmpf[] = {0xEA,0x44,0x33,0x22,0x11,0x2E,0x00};

//make stack executable (because of DEP)
DWORD oldprotect;
DWORD error;
VirtualProtect(&jmpf,7,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&oldprotect);

unsigned int addr = (unsigned int)jmpf;

_asm{
    mov eax, addr
    jmp eax
}
```

The jump disassembles into this:

```
EA 44 33 22 11 2E 00         jmp  002E:11223344
```

But if I execute this jump an access violation exception is thrown on a read at address 0xFFFFFFFF. Im not sure how this jump is related to 0xFFFFFFFF.

I got the OP code from http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html (named jmpf) and the number for the code segment register from http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/lecture.html .

Can someone help me with encoding a direct jump? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to jump directly to a known hard-coded address without assembly magic, you can use `((void (*)(void))0x11223344)();` too.

Comment: this assembles into  mov eax,11223344h;  mov esi,esp;  call eax; No direct jump :(

Comment: Why must you use a direct jump?  Why can't you just use a register- or memory-indirect jump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a direct jump in visual studio you can first store the absolute target address in a variable and the use it in the asm:

```
unsigned int target = 0x11223344;
__asm {
    jmp target
}
```

This will compile as something like this:

```
69044B7C  - FF25 E4330669       JMP DWORD PTR DS:[test.690633E4]
```

This also allows you to have the target address to be specified at compile time and variable.

As for a DIRECT jump... I don't think there is one. The 0xea one you mentioned is a far jump that the OS will not allow you to use. If you really need your address to be hardcoded though, there would be the following workaround for a jump:

```
__asm {
    push 0x11223344
    ret
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't have to worry about it being relative?

Comment: @paulm Sorry there was some false information. Corrected now!

Comment: But this is a memory INDIRECT jump. I need a direct jump with the target address beeing part of the op code.

Comment: @user2252343 I don't think there is a instruction like that. The one you mentioned in your post uses segment registers and the OS will forbid you to use that (exception). An alternative would be "0xE9" jump which is a relative jump though.

Comment: hm does x86 really dont have anything like jmp 0x11223344? Thats really suprising me.

Comment: @user2252343 Pretty sure there is none. I just had an idea though. How about `push 0x11223344 / ret`?

Comment: @user2252343 At the same time... You could also directly hardcode the move to eax: `mov eax, 0x11223344 / jmp eax`